# How to cancel a Task using CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, cancellationtokensource

So I've this code:

```
//CancelationToken
CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = src.Token;
ct.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Abbruch des Tasks"));
//Task
Task t = new Task(() =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            //Throw
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();                        
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "ThrowIfCancellationRequested() liefert eben eine Exception");
        }
    }             

}, ct);
//Run Task and Cancel
t.Start();
src.CancelAfter(350);
t.Wait();

// Get Information
Console.WriteLine("Canceled: {0} . Finished: {1} . Error: {2}",
                    t.IsCanceled, t.IsCompleted, t.IsFaulted);
```

So in this case I canceled my Task but my output in the end is:
"Canceled: False . Finished: True . Error: False"

In my opinion it should be "Canceled:True . Finished:False".
Why do I get this result? Because I try to catch the exception?

I've tried it without the try - catch block, but then my program stops because of the OperationCanceledException. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx). Remove the try..catch and put it around the `t.Wait();` essentially.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're swallowing the exception, thus the task is flagged as finished as you actually handle the exception and it doesn't propagate outwards.

Instead, don't catch the exception inside the delegate, catch it outside:

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = src.Token;
    ct.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Abbruch des Tasks"));

    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }, ct);

    src.Cancel();
    try
    {
        t.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        // Don't actually use an empty catch clause, this is
        // for the sake of demonstration.
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Canceled: {0} . Finished: {1} . Error: {2}",
                       t.IsCanceled, t.IsCompleted, t.IsFaulted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a question, why does the token(ct) need to be added both in the action (line 10) and the task(line 11)?

Comment: Giving the token to the Task constructor lets you cancel scheduling the Task if a cancellation comes before the Task starts running.