# C# - Break Loop from another button

Tags: c#, for-loop, break

In my program i'm starting `for loop` using `button`, I want to break this for loop using another `button`.
For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for( int i = 0; i <  var; i++)
    {
        //doing something
    }
}
```

And using second button break loop,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //breaking loop;
}
```

Need help :)

Comment: @Legends No, you cannot. Both event handlers run on a UI thread, so `button2_Click` will not be entered until `button1_Click` is over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set a flag in `button2_Click()` method and check it in the `button1_Click()`'s loop.
2. In order to process Windows events and allow `button2_Click()` handle to run while iterating, add `Application.DoEvents()` in your loop:

```
bool breakLoop = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    breakLoop = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < var && !breakLoop; i++)
    {
         //doing something
         Application.DoEvents();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    breakLoop = true;
}
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: actually, it can with the help of `Application.DoEvents()`. The latter invokes a callback from running code in the UI thread to the Windows message pump, which in turn processes newly came messages and calls appropriate event handlers including `button2_Click()`. There may be some latency in UI response depending on what `//doing something` actually does, though.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov The line `breakLoop = true;` in `button1_Click` is wrong. It should be `breakLoop = false;`. Please correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because the loop in `button1_Click` event handler will be holding the UI thread. Your user interface will not respond to any event, showing hourglass icon, until the loop is over. This means that `button2_Click` cannot be entered until `button1_Click` has completed.

You need to replace the long-running loop from the event handler with something that runs outside the UI thread. For example, you can use `Task`s, which can be cancelled using `CancellationToken` ([related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35610840/335858)).

Answer (score 0):

Arguably it would be better to use threads and cancellation tokens in some form, rather than the Application.DoEvents(). Something like this:

```
private CancellationTokenSource loopCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                this.loopCanceller.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // exit, if cancelled

                // simulating half a second of work
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                // UI update, Invoke needed because we are in another thread
                Invoke((Action)(() => this.Text = "Iteration " + i)); 
            }

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            loopCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource(); // resetting the canceller
            Invoke((Action)(() => this.Text = "Thread cancelled"));
        }
    }, loopCanceller.Token);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loopCanceller.Cancel();
}
```